# Delete numbers from the existing set of data and create new sets

Tags: java, algorithm

I have List of ranges. Now I will be provided with the List of number & I have to delete the number form the ranges & create new ranges. 
All continous number should come in one range & discontinous number should come in seperate range.

```
public class DriverClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
     Interval i1 = new Interval(5, 9);
     Interval i2 = new Interval(12, 23);
     intervals.add(i1);
     intervals.add(i2);
 
     List<Integer> numbersToBeDeleted = Arrays.asList(6, 7, 19, 21);
  }
}
```

After deleting the 6, 7, 19, 21 
Expected output: [5,5], [8,9], [12,18], [20,20], [22,23]

```
class Interval {
    int start, end;

    Interval(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

I am unable to think through the solution, any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled the below use cases:

1. When the start and end of the existing intervals are the same as the existing intervals, then remove the interval from the list.
2. If the interval to be deleted lies in the between the existing range, then I am dividing the existing interval into 2 intervals excluding the interval to be deleted & adding the 2 new intervals in the list.
3. If the interval to be deleted lies in the boundary value of the existing intervals, then I am not creating the new start/end intervals.

Sample code:

```
public void  deleteIntervals(){

        List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        Interval i1 = new Interval(2, 9);
        Interval i2 = new Interval(12, 27);
        Interval i3 = new Interval(29, 500);
        intervals.add(i1);
        intervals.add(i2);
        intervals.add(i3);

        List<Interval> deleteIntervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        Interval d1 = new Interval(2, 7);
        Interval d2 = new Interval(13, 15);
        Interval d3 = new Interval(18, 20);
        Interval d4 = new Interval(22, 22);
        Interval d5 = new Interval(50, 500);
        Interval d6 = new Interval(22, 22);
        deleteIntervals.add(d1);
        deleteIntervals.add(d2);
        deleteIntervals.add(d3);
        deleteIntervals.add(d4);
        deleteIntervals.add(d5);
        deleteIntervals.add(d6);

        List<Interval> finalDelete = new ArrayList<Interval>();

        for (int i = 0; i < deleteIntervals.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < intervals.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Range to delete: " + deleteIntervals.get(i).start + ", " + deleteIntervals.get(i).end);
                intervals.stream().forEach(ele -> System.out.print("[" + ele.start + ", " + ele.end + "]" + ", "));
                System.out.println();

                if (deleteIntervals.get(i).start == intervals.get(j).start
                        && deleteIntervals.get(i).end == intervals.get(j).end) {
                    intervals.remove(j);
                    break;

                }

                else if (deleteIntervals.get(i).start >= intervals.get(j).start
                        && deleteIntervals.get(i).end <= intervals.get(j).end) {
                    System.out.println("Matched: [" + intervals.get(j).start + ", " + intervals.get(j).end + "]");

                    int newStart = (deleteIntervals.get(i).start - intervals.get(j).start);
                    int newEnd = intervals.get(j).end - (deleteIntervals.get(i).end);

                    if (newStart > 0) {

                        System.out.println("Adding 1: " + "[" + intervals.get(j).start + ","
                                + (intervals.get(j).start + newStart - 1) + "]");
                        finalDelete.add(new Interval(intervals.get(j).start, (intervals.get(j).start + newStart - 1)));

                        intervals.add(new Interval(intervals.get(j).start, (intervals.get(j).start + newStart - 1)));
                    
                    }
                    if (newEnd > 0) {
        
                        System.out.println("Adding 2:" + "[" + (intervals.get(j).end - newEnd + 1) + ","
                                + intervals.get(j).end + "]");
                        finalDelete.add(new Interval((intervals.get(j).end - newEnd + 1), intervals.get(j).end));

                        intervals.add(new Interval((intervals.get(j).end - newEnd + 1), intervals.get(j).end));

                    }
                    intervals.remove(j);
                    break;

                }
            }

        }

        intervals.stream().forEach(ele -> System.out.print("[" + ele.start + ", " + ele.end + "]" + ", "));
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each number to be deleted:

1. Find the index of interval containing that number (if any; if no such interval, you’re done, may consider throwing).
2. Depending:

   1. If the number to be deleted is the only number in the interval, delete the entire interval.
   2. Otherwise if the number is first or last in the interval, shorten the interval.
   3. Otherwise split into two intervals.

You may want to code the condition checking differently, but this should be the basic idea. For deleting and inserting intervals in the list the [`List.remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) and [`List.add(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,E)) methods should be useful.

PS It will probably be convenient to add methods to your `Interval` class to determine whether a number is contained, whether it is first or last, and to shorten the interval at the front or the rear. Maybe even a method for splitting into two intervals.